# Create new encryption with coordinates of PUK and BrainpoolP256R1 Curve

Tags: javascript, encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption

I need to encrypt a jwt with coordinates of a public key by using the BrainpoolP256R1 curve.

So what I got from API is:

```
{
     ...
    "kty": "EC",
    "crv": "BP-256",
    "x": "QLpJ_LpFx-6yJhsb4OvHwU1khLnviiOwYOvmf5clK7w",
    "y": "AJh7pJ3zZKDJkm8rbeG69GBooTosXJgSsvNFH0i3Vxnu"
}
```

In a reference implementation seeing below they using this `x` and `y` coordinates to create the new encryption

C# reference code:

```
...
Console.Out.WriteLine($"Coordinates: {encJson["x"]} {encJson["y"]}");

X9ECParameters x9EC = ECNamedCurveTable.GetByOid(TeleTrusTObjectIdentifiers.BrainpoolP256R1);
ECDomainParameters domainParams = new ECDomainParameters(x9EC.Curve, x9EC.G, x9EC.N, x9EC.H, x9EC.GetSeed());

var x = new BigInteger(1, Base64Url.Decode(encJson["x"].ToString()));
var y = new BigInteger(1, Base64Url.Decode(encJson["y"].ToString()));
var ecPoint = domainParams.Curve.CreatePoint(x, y);

var key = new ECPublicKeyParameters(ecPoint, domainParams);
....
```

However, is it possible to archive this running in a browser with javascript?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42970290/14032355

Comment: @ikhvjs they use a nodejs library and it seems like they try to archive something different for me